# Email deliverability -- Whitelist solution or Email delivery service?

Tags: email, whitelist

our company is encountering the same recurring problem - email deliverability. A lot of our emails are still getting trapped in yahoo and gmail spam filters. We followed yahoo's best practices guide as well as tips Ive found on serverfault. (setting up DKIM, SPF) And even took the Email Server Test (http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/)

Now my question is: has anyone had success using whitelist solutions like [goodmail](http://www.goodmailsystems.com/products/certified-email/) or EmailReach? Alternatively, Im beginning to think that going with a email delivery service like Mailchimp will save me the headache and future stress of managing our email lists.

So whitelist solution or just fork up the money and send via an email delivery service?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the exact blockage message and if possible the URL that you recieve in the log files when your emails are blocked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things i would suggest trying before you go the pay-for route (although that may be the only option in the end).

1. Fill out and submit the [Yahoo Bulk sender form](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/bulkv2.html)
2. Make sure you are complying with [Google Bulk Senders gudeline](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126) as well as yahoo's. There is a troubleshoot link at the bottom that may be helpful too.

One of the big problems today for legitamate bulk senders is that people don't trust unsubscribe links, and just flag messages as spam. A big component of any spam solution from the 'big guys' is user input.

Answer (score 0):

You also may have some poor wording/phrasing in your message bodies.  There's a [few](http://www.contactology.com/check_mqs.php) [online](http://www.mailingcheck.com/) [spam score checks](http://flashmarketing.com/spam-check.htm) you can do, which will grade your emails against various anti-spam heuristics; might give you an idea of whether it's a question of the legitimacy of your mail server infrastructure or if it's just poorly-worded emails.